# Can you use a Wizard's charm on another player's monster?

Tags: munchkin

The card says "You may discard your whole hand (minimum 3 cards) to charm a single Monster instead of fighting it." Can I use this on another player to charm his monster? Or does it only apply to a monster I am fighting?

Comment: It specifically days you have to be about to fight it in the ability!

Answer (score 13):

The charms only work for wizards in the combat.  From the [Munchin FAQ](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/faq/)

> **Q.** Can a Wizard use his charm ability if he's not involved in the combat?
>
> **A.** No. The card says this is something he may do instead of fighting a monster. It's not for interfering with others' fights, so the Wizard in question must be the munchkin who opened the door or is helping.

Nice try but you can't charm an opponent's monster unless you are helping in combat.  If you somehow manage to become part of combat, you can betray them by charming to prevent them from killing a monster and gaining a level.

Comment: You may be able to force the current player to accept your help, though - than you are part of the combat.

Comment: @mthomas yeah, that's totally legit, devious, and truly Munchkiny.

Answer (score -4):

Yes. The wizard's Charm ability can be used on any monster during a combat. He/she does not have to be in combat in order to use the ability.

Comment: This appears to contradict the Munchkin FAQ quoted in the other answer. Are you actually from Steve Jackson Games or is that just a name you chose? You may want to base this in rules or something.